# Is it possible to reduce the number of "Site Links" displayed in google search results through Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, sitelinks

I know I am able to demote links I don't want to appear, but what I really want to do is reduce the number of site links from 6 to 4.

Does anyone know if this is possible or how to achieve it?

Comment: Google generate sitelinks automatically, If you demote some links, then it will not appear in search result, so if you demote two links, then Google will show 4 site links, but in future may be Google will pick up another links and start showing 6 or 8 links again. In short, you have no more control on it. Just demote those links, that you don't like it, so may be Google will display only 2 site links or 4 site links, it is their choice :)

Comment: Why would you want to reduce the number?   Most webmasters ask for as much real estate in the Google search results as possible.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the content on the site is predominantly user generated or behind an authentication wall. We're not really interest in highlighting pages for either of these cases as site links. As for maximizing our google real estate, we're leveraging google structured data tags to control the knowledge graph and rich snippet views. If I'm unable to trim down the number of site links, I suppose I'll get the marketing team to provide some kind of static marketing content to show to unauthenticated users (instead of the current behavior of redirecting to login).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way currently to limit the number of site links you have on your Google search result entry. You can demote a site link URL from [webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitelinks) if you have added your web property to the search console.

Google automatically decides which URL's to set as site links, and while you can demote a URL from being a site link you can only demote up to 100 URL's, and only after they have been promoted to site links, and demotions are only effective for 90 days. Google also does not guarantee that URL's which have been demoted won't be promoted to a site link again in the future once the demotion expires.

**Sources:**

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en